# What is Newark's (EWR) deplaning procedure for regional jets?

Tags: air-travel, short-connections, ewr

I'm flying tomorrow into Newark (EWR) on an Embraer RJ135 / RJ140 / RJ145 and most likely landing at gate 130Z.

What is the procedure for deplaning from regional jets and turboprops at that airport?  Will there be a normal jetway or will we have to wait for everyone to get off and claim their gate-checked bags before taking a bus to the terminal.

(I have a long layover scheduled, but we're expecting weather at the originating airport, so I'm wondering about whether the deplaning procedure is going to be an extra impediment to making my connection.)

Update: It looks like this flight normally lands at gate 130z -- today's flight was delayed due to weather and is arriving at A27.  I know about the airside shuttle from A to C (where my connection will probably leave from) but let me know if deplaning from a regional jet is significantly different at the two different terminals.

Comment: [This discussion](https://www.airliners.net/forum/viewtopic.php?t=1357917) says that 130v-z are bus gates.  Not exactly authoritative, though.

Comment: I edited to fix some terminology that was bugging me: the Embraer RJ135 family are *regional jets*, not turboprops and not [turbojets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turbojet) (their engines are *turbofans*).  Anyway, welcome to the site!

Comment: @NateEldredge thanks for correcting the terminology for me

Comment: I would be prepared for all possibilities. When there is bad weather, either at an airport or on its routes, flights may be delayed, keeping gates busy longer than scheduled. That can cause gate changes for other flights.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan thanks -- in the end there's nothing I can do but hope anyhow, just wondering how regional jets are typically deplaned at this airport.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are no turboprops flying United livery these days ([nor Delta nor American](https://www.inc.com/bill-murphy-jr/with-1-history-making-american-airlines-flight-this-week-us-airline-travel-changed-forever.html)); the ERJ135, ERJ140, and ERJ145 are all regional jets, not turboprops. That said, the smaller RJs can use the hardstand that was used for turboprop flights, accessed via the C130​*n* "virtual" gates (V–Z). Most of United's current operation in Terminal A is regional jets as well.

If you land at C130​*n*, you will deplane down stairs to the tarmac, pick up any gate-checked (i.e. green-tagged) bags, and board a bus. Once all passengers have deplaned and boarded the bus, it will drive you back to the terminal, where you will climb a staircase onto the airbridge for gate C71 (near the inter-terminal shuttle) or C130.

If you arrive at Terminal A, the larger jets (e.g. E170) will deplane onto a Jetway just as a mainline flight would. For the smaller RJs you may take stairs down to the tarmac, retrieve your gate-checked bags, and then walk to the staircase to the airbridge, but I have not done this transfer myself at terminal A in some time.

Arrivals are calculated from the time the bus arrives at the gate, so you may expect the schedule to be slightly padded if the normal operation is to a remote stand. From anecdotal reports at FlyerTalk, the time to transfer from a C130​*n* arrival to another C departure is comparable for an A terminal arrival to a C departure, using the A-C airside shuttle.